# Tableau: Create histogram bins using calculated field

Tags: histogram, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

I am trying to create a histogram on Tableau using a calculated field but I am unable to do so.

The following are the relevant dimensions & measures in my data source:

Dimension(s):

1. Customer Name

Measure(s):

1. Total Units (Continuous)
2. Rate (Continuous)
3. Paid Amount (Continous)

Calculated Field(s):

1. **Median Rate Discount**: This field is calculated using the formula:

> MEDIAN( 1- ( ([Rate]*[Total Units])/SUM[Paid Amount] )

Once I have the calculated field **Median Rate Discount**, I am unable to create bins as it does not give me an option. The histogram would be represent various customers.

I understand that the issue is related to the fact that this calculated field contains aggregation but I do not know how I can fix it.

Additionally, I would also like to a histogram after creating another calculated field using MAX[Rate] before generating the **Median Max Rate Discount** field using the formula shared above. Would this field have a separate type of problem?

Comment: To operate on aggregated values, you can implement your own bins with an aggregate calc, an LOD calc or a table calc -- just not a record calc. The DIV() function may be helpful for mapping your values into bins of your desired size.